# Integrating swagger-maven-plugin into Spring application

Tags: spring, swagger

I'm getting hard time trying to incorporate Swagger into my Spring application. I'm trying to just generate `.json` file using `com.github.kongchen:swagger-maven-plugin:3.1.0` and `io.swagger:swagger-core:1.5.0` for annotations, but generated file is totally empty:

```
{
  "swagger" : "2.0",
  "info" : {
    "version" : "v1",
    "title" : "KVS"
  }
}
```

controller example

```
@RestController
@Api(
    tags = { "k/v" },
    value = "Main microservice entrypoint",
    produces = "application/json",
    consumes = "application/json",
    protocols = "http,https"
)
class AbcController {
    @ApiOperation(value = "/")
    @ApiResponses({
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Request entry", response = KvsEntry.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Entry not found", response = Void.class)
    })
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<KvsEntry> create(@Validated @RequestBody KvsEntry kvsEntry) {
        kvsEntry = keyValueService.saveEntry(kvsEntry);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(kvsEntry, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

I still can get some results using `<springmvc>false</springmvc>` configuration and JAX-RS annotations (not quite correct, i'd say), but that would be quite counterproductive. What may i be doing wrong?

Comment: got the same problem... did you make any progress?

Comment: @MichaelWiles sadly, but not. I've made decision to maintain hand-written swagger .yml files since it takes nearly the same time as putting all annotations on.

Comment: Start with swagger file is better way to go, I think. JSON and Java Object is not exactly same during presentation.

Answer (score 3):

Please check simple sample of working plugin with Spring MVC annotations on this repo:

https://github.com/khipis/swagger-maven-example

Plugin is sensitive on dependencies versions and presence or not of specific annotations.

Comment: i hope i'll have some time to check it soon, thank you